# ansible 2.9.2 getting skip_reason: "Conditional result was False" even when meeting my conditional string

Tags: ansible

I am trying to install some RPMs, only when variables are defined.
but I am getting skip messages even if the variable was defined.
I have tried the three different when conditions and all were skipped.

here is my task:

```
- name: Install elasticsearch packages
  package: name={{ package.item }} state=installed
  when: ansible_distribution == item.when
  with_items:
    - { package: "logstash-{{ logstash_ver }}", when: (logstash_ver is defined) and (logstash_ver|length > 0) }
    - { package: "kibana-{{ kibana_ver }}", when: ( inventory_hostname == kibana_ver ) }
    - { package: "elasticsearch-{{ elasticsearch_ver }}", when: ( host_enviroment == elasticsearch_ver ) }

Here is the message I am getting:
skipping: [host1] => (item={u'when': u'(logstash_ver is defined) and (logstash_ver|length > 0)', u'package': u'logstash-7.9.0-1'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"package": "logstash-7.9.0-1", "when": "(logstash_ver is defined) and (logstash_ver|length > 0)"}, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}

skipping: [host1] => (item={u'when': u'( inventory_hostname == kibana_ver )', u'package': u'kibana-7.9.1-1'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"package": "kibana-7.9.1-1", "when": "( inventory_hostname == kibana_ver )"}, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}

skipping: [host1] => (item={u'when': u'( host_enviroment == elasticsearch_ver )', u'package': u'elasticsearch-7.8.1-1'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"package": "elasticsearch-7.8.1-1", "when": "( host_enviroment == elasticsearch_ver )"}, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
```

at the end, I should install about 15 rpms, so I really want to use with_items with the when condition.

Any Idea how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really have distributions named `'( host_enviroment == elasticsearch_ver )'`, or `'(logstash_ver is defined) and (logstash_ver|length > 0)'` ? Because this is what you are testing for...

Comment: yes, i did add it to the extra vars.
the following tasks runs before and check that variables has value and defined.

Comment: the following tasks runs before and check that variables has value and defined.

- shell: echo "The variable 'logstash_ver' is defined and not empty"
  when: (logstash_ver is defined) and (logstash_ver|length > 0) 


and the result is ok, for each one of the above
"stdout_lines": ["The variable 'logstash_ver' is defined and not empty"]

Comment: This was a rethoric question... your `when` clause is `ansible_distribution == item.when`. You are literally comparing the content of `ansible_distribution` varialble (which contains e.g. 'Ubuntu', or 'Centos') to the exact string content of your `item.when` e.g. `'( host_enviroment == elasticsearch_ver )'`. 1) I don't think you want `item.when` content to be a string but the result of evaluating the vars (add jinja2 markers arround) 2) even when evaluated, I don't think you want to compare the result to your current OS name (which is not a boolean). You need to edit your question for clarity.

Comment: thank you! it was helpful
I have changed the when conditions and it works !